# Dockerize a Visual Studio C++ project on Windows home

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, docker

I am new to Docker, using windows 10 home edition, and want to create a docker image for my C++ project developed with visual studio. As far as I understand, the image I need to create is going to be a windows image, and therefore I need to install “Docker for windows” and enable the Hyper-V feature. This is not possible with my windows home edition, as Hyper-V is available for windows 10 pro only. The other alternative, using “Docker toolbox” and a virtualbox linux VM, does not support creating or pulling windows containers. Did I miss something? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Doubtful. Virtualbox (a full VM, IOW) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows Linux Subsystem: https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4

EDIT: On second read of your question you probably want to have a windows-container for visual studio. This solutions makes Linux-containers possible, but doesn't help with windows images...

Comment: Thanks. I decided to docker it on an unubtu container.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you are unable to install Docker for Windows Home edition, as it requires Hyper V virtualization.

So these are your options:

You will need to install Docker Toolbox which uses VirtualBox instead.

Docs and setup info available here:
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Release downloads available here:
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases

Toolbox will install everything you need including VirtualBox.

You may also need to enable virtualization in your computer's BIOS settings. This will be different for each manufacturer, please refer to their documentation on which keys to use to access these settings on reboot.

After Toolbox is finished installing, open the Docker Quickstart Terminal. This will complete the setup and provision your VirtualBox machine.

**Check your install:**

Launch the Docker QuickStart terminal and type the command:

`docker run hello-world`

This should pull down the test container and print hello-world to your screen.